# Upstart not respawning Sidekiq daemon

Tags: ubuntu, sidekiq, upstart

I have problems with my sidekiq daemon restart. Upstart is not respawning the daemon when the daemon crashes. Here is my Upstart init file.

```
description "Sidekiq worker"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]

# change to match your deployment user
setuid user
setgid user
env HOME=/home/user

# restart the process if it crashes
respawn
# respawn a max of 3 times within 30 seconds
respawn limit 3 30

script
# this script runs in /bin/sh by default
# respawn as bash so we can source in rbenv
exec /bin/bash <<'EOT'
  # Pick your poison :) Or none if you're using a system wide installed Ruby.
  # rbenv
  # source /home/apps/.bash_profile
  # OR
  # source /home/apps/.profile
  # OR system:
  # source /etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh
  #
  # rvm
  source /home/user/.rvm/bin/rvm  

  cd /var/www/myapp/current
  exec sidekiq -c 10 -e production -L log/sidekiq.log -d
EOT
end script
```

When I start daemon with Sercive start, it works but It not respawn if kill it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `-L log/sidekiq.log -d`.  You do not use custom logfiles or daemonize with Upstart.

Comment: Can you help me to solve my problem? I am facing same issue to respawn daemon once it crashed.